# How to loop through the items in the Ext.menu.Menu box-Extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm using the Ext.menu.Menu to list items and want to loop through them to look for a specific value.

```
new Ext.Container({                
          width: 560,
            height: 250,
            layout: 'hbox',
            items: [
                new Ext.menu.Menu({
                    items: [
                        {
                            text: 'Today',
                            handler: function() {
                            },
                            scope: this
                        }
                    ].concat([
                            {
                                text: 'Yestaerday',
                                handler: function() {
                                },
                                scope: this
                            }, {
                                text: 'Month'
                                handler: function() {
                                },
                                scope: this
                            }
                        ]).concat([
                            {
                                text: 'Year',
                                handler: function() {
                                },
                                scope: this
                         }]
 })
```

in the above code i'm trying to remove the items whose text value is"Yestaerday and Month". How can I loop through the menu items to find the equivalent text value to be removed?thx

Comment: What's with the weird concat code?

Comment: I agree...unfortunately this is an existing appl code, cant modify much in that..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll just have to create your own 'component query' type function that will loop the menu items and find the matches.

Have a look at this fiddle as a starting point:

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1chu

Answer (score 0):

Try to use ComponenetQuery

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('button[text=Yestarday],button[text=Month]');
```

you will get button objects.

Comment: I'm actually using EXT3(sorry did not mention earlier) and Ext.ComponentQuery throws undefined for me. hence im unable to use this component..any other alternative for EXT3?thx